# Cannot change link colour in bootstrap 4 button

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I cannot override the default link colour in bootstrap 4 and sass. Here is the code I'm using to override the _variables.scss defaults to far:

```
$body-bg: #f4f4f4;
$body-color: #c0b283;
$link-color: #c0b283;
$link-hover-decoration: none;
$navbar-dark-color: #c0b283;
$navbar-dark-hover-color: #9c906a;
$navbar-padding-y: 0px;
$list-group-bg: black;
$list-group-color: #c0b283;
$theme-colors: (
        "dark": #000,
        "danger": #ff4136
);
```

and here is the button I'm targetting:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mt-4">
        <form action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="mainSearchBox">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Submit</a>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Seems to be the same issue if I use this too:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mt-4">
        <form action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="mainSearchBox">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Whatever I do, the link just stays white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
.btn {
    background-color: $link-color !important;
    border-color: $link-color !important;
}
```

Could be that you need to check your main SASS/SCSS file too. Just to make sure bootstrap is above the file you are using to style your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$link-color: #c0b283 !important;
```

Comment: I cannot use that as it errors to say it's not a colour when I compile it. Plus, the colors for the link I set work ok whenever there's a link not in a button